# How to activate Analysis ToolPak in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I tried to activate the Analysis ToolPak in Excel 2013 but when I went to `File -> Options -> Add-Ins` I couldn't make it become an "Active Application Add-ins" no matter what I tried.

[image]

Also, when I check my `Data` thing I don't see any `Data Analysis` option.

[image]

So, how can I do regression analysis in Excel 2013?

Comment: You need to choose the `Go...` button (at the bottom). Then in the window that pops up, check the `Analysis ToolPak`. Choose `OK` to enable it.

Comment: Glad it helped. I posted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose the <kbd>Go...</kbd> button (at the bottom). Then in the window that pops up, check the `Analysis ToolPak`. Choose <kbd>OK</kbd> to enable it.